# Beautifulsoup isn't returning the html that I see when I inpect using the dev tools

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the https://findamortgagebroker.com/ site.

When I use a search url such as "https://findamortgagebroker.com/?search=San%20Diego&page=2", I don't get the tags that I see when I do the inspection using the dev tools.

I want to scrape for 'a' elements having 'class' equals 'clickable-tile-contact'.

```
def get_soup(url):
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    time.sleep(10)
    html_page = urlopen(req).read()
    time.sleep(10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
    return soup

url="https://findamortgagebroker.com/?search=San%20Diego&page=2"

soup=get_soup(url)

links=soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'clickable-tile-contact'})
```

Comment: What's the tages that you can't see after finished the search? You  have to clearify and show us that tags aka html  portion or what  you want to scrape.?Your question is too unclear about your expected ResultSet. Please modify a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Fazlul. I edited my question. I want to scrape for 'a' elements having 'class' equals 'clickable-tile-contact'. I look forward to receiving your advice.

Comment: Thanks. Now you have to  input a search keyword  address, city or zip code in the search box.  Would you tell  a zip code or city?

Comment: I already added 'San Diego' in the search box. I used it in the above url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Required data is loaded from external source via `API` as AJAX request as plain HTML tree as post method. So to get the right data you have to apply API url instead.

**Full working code as an example:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url ='https://findamortgagebroker.com/home/SearchContacts/'

headers= {
    "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}


body = "searchModel%5BSearchText%5D=San+Diego&searchModel%5BPageNumber%5D=2&searchModel%5BRadius%5D=50&searchModel%5BResultsPerPage%5D=20&searchModel%5BCaptchaToken%5D=03AEkXODDG8q9JqC--gCpxJK_Kevp506iB5o5Z7ilzY3Ge6GbYQaoX9jcOJqEyC6TG159L5KSvPoE43UlBxGMYW2jlNcnc0ING0sFeQO2RZIOui0YnNAaByRIVrjaluwaNi7WCE2FykjJNI0B5FNLB7nJjnr9N7YEeUkY13km0wRN3vfyqPh-bVdpahCir00GzE-pQyXU_o84bY1dCWRNQten7O_cnmdcA0ucEPxFeO3WIbMkUkUqqMC5vpAUiz_VttmYMyRETidTuaI6rHE2_AjGbUr6Z61vXFr-dXAC63alA15gGu8ypGRljtHS2wmfNSSySrtegnFxD3txZZ4d2KDk4ugBXLfh3jNUHM_KcKF6Rkp0WOHx7-D-4CEfMf-mC9zJ6FnVqJx3FTZiOrwcelQ0dW1OxdHuHlCVPPQlzIzcFMfsTJOsCLj3JNZTEgkQ6Eicl6dkVV-F-CRPd4fQZ2D_u3dDmrIaCIQJJ4LlQuSYXhLt-6QMcnFXceygadkKGqeiGQZcdUeagF6c8zz9OUg5g2ppXkCu-WsH08e-ei7sRHspA3Rdwh6sylcr8fqFlxDNmEXTI4CH1nRgLvJMuXr6KdcY3AWNhwA&searchModel%5BIsVendorRequest%5D=false&searchModel%5BVendorIdentifier%5D=0&searchModel%5BCaptchaV2%5D=false"
res = requests.post(api_url,data=body,headers=headers)
#print(res)


soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

data =[]
for item in soup.select('.clickable-tile-contact'):
    data.append({
        'href':item.get('href'),
       
        })
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\AndresCamacho26826'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\DavidStein65836'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\DanielRamirez28222'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\DavidHolland56665'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\EvbeniiMalenko57387'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\AmirNurani66326'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\MarialuisaSarrizLira37868'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\DejaCorreia53368'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\JulioRugama72662'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\MarthaMunoz26537'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\CarlosMunoz55258'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\AndreaCutuk35775'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\LauraPardo64458'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\KatiePike37454'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\JustinGuthrie27854'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\GinoSalvaggio54863'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\AnnaValencia55287'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\ArtinMousakhan27554'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\GloriaPereira45832'}, {'href': 'https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\\NickKinnard38652'}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Fazlul. Could you pls advise how did you get the body?

Comment: body is the payload data of the api url . From the payload tab click on view urlencode then you will get such plain text and just copy and paste and use as sting of the body

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate all your help. I marked the answer as the solution, and upvoted it. You deserve all the best. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm failing to get the same payload data as yours. In Firefox, developer tools, I navigated to the Network tab, and then chose the Post request of 'home/SearchContacts/'. Then 'Request', then 'Form data'. The data I got is not working, and not similar to what you pasted above. Could you pls guide me about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I think the payload data will change with each page. Will it be possible to extract this data automatically instead of copying them through inspection by browser development tools?

Comment: No there is no alternative way to send payload data automatically in data parameters as its post request. Another thing that you can do , you can send payload data as dict and I can't garanree in this case it will work properly.  Making Pagination is possible from the payload data easily using for loop and that's an another question.

Comment: I issued a new question @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368113/can-i-get-the-payload-of-post-request-data-parameters-automatically-to-use-with. Could you pls help me with it. Also, as I mentioned above, I'm even having a problem extracting the correct payload through inspection. Is there any mistake in the steps I stated in the above comment. Am I getting it from a wrong location. Only the payload that you put in your code is working.

Comment: Hi @Fazlul, I noticed that you answered my new question last Thursday. I was travelling on that day, and I'm just back to home today. Today, I was searching for you answer and couldn't find it. Have you deleted it? I still need your help on it. Could you pls answer my new question?

Comment: @Mohamed Hedeya, Got it, pls mark as ans