# Can I get the payload of post request data parameters automatically to use with subsequent Beautifulsoup parsing? How can I change pages?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Referring to the answer of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74366261/beautifulsoup-isnt-returning-the-html-that-i-see-when-i-inpect-using-the-dev-to/74367014?noredirect=1#comment131288804_74367014), how can I automate getting the payload from https://findamortgagebroker.com instead of copying it through inspecting the site using development tools. Also, how can I change the pages? I think changing the pages will require a new CaptchToken?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url ='https://findamortgagebroker.com/home/SearchContacts/'

headers= {
    "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}


body = "searchModel%5BSearchText%5D=San+Diego&searchModel%5BPageNumber%5D=2&searchModel%5BRadius%5D=50&searchModel%5BResultsPerPage%5D=20&searchModel%5BCaptchaToken%5D=03AEkXODDG8q9JqC--gCpxJK_Kevp506iB5o5Z7ilzY3Ge6GbYQaoX9jcOJqEyC6TG159L5KSvPoE43UlBxGMYW2jlNcnc0ING0sFeQO2RZIOui0YnNAaByRIVrjaluwaNi7WCE2FykjJNI0B5FNLB7nJjnr9N7YEeUkY13km0wRN3vfyqPh-bVdpahCir00GzE-pQyXU_o84bY1dCWRNQten7O_cnmdcA0ucEPxFeO3WIbMkUkUqqMC5vpAUiz_VttmYMyRETidTuaI6rHE2_AjGbUr6Z61vXFr-dXAC63alA15gGu8ypGRljtHS2wmfNSSySrtegnFxD3txZZ4d2KDk4ugBXLfh3jNUHM_KcKF6Rkp0WOHx7-D-4CEfMf-mC9zJ6FnVqJx3FTZiOrwcelQ0dW1OxdHuHlCVPPQlzIzcFMfsTJOsCLj3JNZTEgkQ6Eicl6dkVV-F-CRPd4fQZ2D_u3dDmrIaCIQJJ4LlQuSYXhLt-6QMcnFXceygadkKGqeiGQZcdUeagF6c8zz9OUg5g2ppXkCu-WsH08e-ei7sRHspA3Rdwh6sylcr8fqFlxDNmEXTI4CH1nRgLvJMuXr6KdcY3AWNhwA&searchModel%5BIsVendorRequest%5D=false&searchModel%5BVendorIdentifier%5D=0&searchModel%5BCaptchaV2%5D=false"
res = requests.post(api_url,data=body,headers=headers)
#print(res)


soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

data =[]
for item in soup.select('.clickable-tile-contact'):
    data.append({
        'href':item.get('href'),
       
        })
print(data)
```

Comment: Yes, each search and next page will require a new CaptchaToken parameter in the payload. If you trace back through the [request initiators](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/212-request-initiator-pane/), you might notice that it's fetched via a POST request made by [recaptcha__en.js](https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/Ixi5IiChXmIG6rRkjUa1qXHT/recaptcha__en.js) and I have no idea how someone might replicate whatever that does - I think it would be simpler to use a browser automation tool like selenium instead in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the payload data, go to payload > form Data > view source and click on View source

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

api_url ='https://findamortgagebroker.com/home/SearchContacts/'

headers= {
    "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

data =[]
for page in range(1,42):
    body = f"searchModel%5BSearchText%5D=San+Diego&searchModel%5BPageNumber%5D={page}&searchModel%5BRadius%5D=50&searchModel%5BResultsPerPage%5D=20&searchModel%5BCaptchaToken%5D=03AEkXODDG8q9JqC--gCpxJK_Kevp506iB5o5Z7ilzY3Ge6GbYQaoX9jcOJqEyC6TG159L5KSvPoE43UlBxGMYW2jlNcnc0ING0sFeQO2RZIOui0YnNAaByRIVrjaluwaNi7WCE2FykjJNI0B5FNLB7nJjnr9N7YEeUkY13km0wRN3vfyqPh-bVdpahCir00GzE-pQyXU_o84bY1dCWRNQten7O_cnmdcA0ucEPxFeO3WIbMkUkUqqMC5vpAUiz_VttmYMyRETidTuaI6rHE2_AjGbUr6Z61vXFr-dXAC63alA15gGu8ypGRljtHS2wmfNSSySrtegnFxD3txZZ4d2KDk4ugBXLfh3jNUHM_KcKF6Rkp0WOHx7-D-4CEfMf-mC9zJ6FnVqJx3FTZiOrwcelQ0dW1OxdHuHlCVPPQlzIzcFMfsTJOsCLj3JNZTEgkQ6Eicl6dkVV-F-CRPd4fQZ2D_u3dDmrIaCIQJJ4LlQuSYXhLt-6QMcnFXceygadkKGqeiGQZcdUeagF6c8zz9OUg5g2ppXkCu-WsH08e-ei7sRHspA3Rdwh6sylcr8fqFlxDNmEXTI4CH1nRgLvJMuXr6KdcY3AWNhwA&searchModel%5BIsVendorRequest%5D=false&searchModel%5BVendorIdentifier%5D=0&searchModel%5BCaptchaV2%5D=false"
    res = requests.post(api_url,data=body,headers=headers)
    #print(res)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

    for item in soup.select('.clickable-tile-contact'):
        data.append({
            'href':item.get('href')
           })

print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                  href
0    https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\Andres...
1    https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\DavidS...
2    https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\Daniel...
3    https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\DavidH...
4    https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\Evbeni...
..                                                 ...
795  https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\Benjam...
796  https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\DiegoS...
797  https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\IvanLa...
798  https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\KevinM...
799  https://findamortgagebroker.com/Profile\DarenG...

[800 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, from which browser, and which menu should I go to payload > form Data > view source? Also, how to get it automatically if possible?